# Nullable Field and SQL Is Null Issue

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, nullable, isnull

There are tons of Q&A on stackoverflow related to my question , but I cannot deduce the reasoning of the issue and the solution that works best in this scenario;

So I've  a method that allows you to pass a parentID, and based on the value records will be filtered using a LINQ query. The field in the database allows NULL values. Now If I compare fields using `==` operator in the where clause, the sql emitted is wrong (it doesn't uses `IS NULL` for the comparison), and hence query yields 0 results. I solved this using `Object.Equals()` method. That worked, but now I get an exception on passing a NON NULL value, an integer

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

So I wrote a simple method

```
using (TestEntities context = new Entities())
{
    return from c in context.ItemMappings
           where c.ParentID.Equals(parentID)
           select new ItemDTO
           {
               ItemID = c.Item.ItemID,
               ItemName = c.Item.ItemName,
               ItemType = new ItemTypeDTO
               {
                   TypeID = c.Item.Type.TypeID,
                   TypeName =c.Item.Type.TypeName
               };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your problem would also occur if it's SQL.  You have to handle null explicitly, and this should work:

```
Where (parentID == null && c.ParentID == null) || (parentID == c.ParentID)
```

This assumes that you want a null to match.  If you want null to return all the results unfiltered, instead do:

```
Where (parentID == null) || (parentID == c.ParentID)
```

I've had trouble with this even sometimes, and found the way LINQ would translate correctly all the time was to do:

```
Where (parentID == null) || (parentID != null && parentID == c.ParentID)
```

This is because even in SQL, if you do where `ParentID = @ParentID`, a null match returns no results, and you have to use `ISNULL` to escape it to blank.

Comment: I'll try that in a while, and I know by looking at it that it will work.
BTW, I understand the reasoning that I'll get the same issue in SQL , but thought LINQ engine will emit the right SQL based on my value. I was confused more about the exception that I got while using Object.Equals

Comment: I'm not sure of the particularities of that error; that one is a new one to me...  Unfortunately EF does not look to make those kinds of optimizations in SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

To allow nullable You can also try Like this

```
  GSectionID = emp.SectionID ?? Guid.Empty,
```

Answer (score 1):

In EF6 you can use UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior to solve this problem. You need to set the context option UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior  to true and it's going to be behave like C#.

```
objectContext.ContextOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior = true;
```

You can see more in the following link: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/145